# Uncaught TypeError: data.some is not a function

Tags: magento-2.1.8

In magento 2 Suddenly i got this error on product-> catalog -> relevant product  . And round circle keep sniping in console I got this

```
select.js:67 Uncaught TypeError: data.some is not a function
at findFirst (select.js:67)
    at UiClass.clear (select.js:285)
    at UiClass.setInitialValue (select.js:299)
    at UiClass.setInitialValue (wrapper.js:109)
    at UiClass.initialize (abstract.js:70)
    at UiClass.initialize (wrapper.js:109)
    at UiClass._super (wrapper.js:106)
    at UiClass.initialize (select.js:119)
    at UiClass.initialize (wrapper.js:109)
    at new UiClass (class.js:49)
```

Comment: now please try this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45719396/uncaught-typeerror-data-some-is-not-a-function

Answer (score 7):

In `{base_url}/files/html/vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/web/js/form/element/select.js`

**from**

```
        data.some(function (node) {
            value = node.value;

            if (Array.isArray(value)) {
                value = findFirst(value);
            }

            return !_.isUndefined(value);
});
```

**to**

```
       data = _.some(data, function (node) {
            value = node.value;
            if (Array.isArray(value)) {
                value = findFirst(value);
            }

            return !_.isUndefined(value);
 });
```

Comment: Is it worked for you?@Rama Chandran

Comment: yes it worked. thanks Rama Chandran M

Comment: It worked! Thankyou

Answer (score 4):

Were you able to resolve this? In case you weren't-- and in case you're using composer-- here are the steps to fix it:

In your composer.json:

-Require Composer Patches in the "require" section:

`"cweagans/composer-patches": "^1.6"`

In "extras":

```
"patches": {
      "magento/module-ui": {
          "some.data is not a function": "patches/module-ui-patch-1.diff"
      }
 }
```

Then create web/patches/module-ui-patch-1.diff:

```
diff --git a/view/base/web/js/form/element/select.js 
b/view/base/web/js/form/element/select.js
index 0c266b9..22fe498 100644
--- a/view/base/web/js/form/element/select.js
+++ b/view/base/web/js/form/element/select.js
@@ -64,16 +64,17 @@ define([
 function findFirst(data) {
     var value;

-        data.some(function (node) {
-            value = node.value;
-
-            if (Array.isArray(value)) {
-                value = findFirst(value);
-            }
+        if (data instanceof Array) {
+            data.some(function (node) {
+                value = node.value;

-            return !_.isUndefined(value);
-        });
+                if (Array.isArray(value)) {
+                    value = findFirst(value);
+                }

+                return !_.isUndefined(value);
+            });
+        }
          return value;
 }
```

Comment: can explain little bit in detail, i am also facing same issue, i modified the composer.json, but how to add patch to js file? Where do i need to move the patch,

Comment: Hey @jafarpinjar , did you create the patches folder in your installation route with the above diff file inside of it?