# Magento 2 Uncaught TypeError: data.some is not a function

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I have found below error in console on backend while editing customer from customer grid.
Path: Customers-> All Customers -> Edit.

> Uncaught TypeError: data.some is not a function
>       at findFirst (eval at require.load (58d22521c2a079102fb0d912e124e25b.min.js:180), :5:41)
>       at UiClass.clear (eval at require.load (58d22521c2a079102fb0d912e124e25b.min.js:180), :13:271)
>       at UiClass.setInitialValue (eval at require.load (58d22521c2a079102fb0d912e124e25b.min.js:180), :13:406)
>       at UiClass.eval [as setInitialValue] (eval at require.load (58d22521c2a079102fb0d912e124e25b.min.js:180), :5:186)
>       at UiClass.initialize (eval at require.load (58d22521c2a079102fb0d912e124e25b.min.js:180), :3:1152)
>       at UiClass.eval [as initialize] (eval at require.load (58d22521c2a079102fb0d912e124e25b.min.js:180), :5:186)
>       at UiClass._super (eval at require.load (58d22521c2a079102fb0d912e124e25b.min.js:180), :5:147)
>       at UiClass.initialize (eval at require.load (58d22521c2a079102fb0d912e124e25b.min.js:180), :8:172)
>       at UiClass.eval [as initialize] (eval at require.load (58d22521c2a079102fb0d912e124e25b.min.js:180), :5:186)
>       at new UiClass (eval at require.load (58d22521c2a079102fb0d912e124e25b.min.js:180), :5:16)

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: have you customized anything related to customer form?

Comment: Yes I have modified customer grid.

Comment: try this hope this will help : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/197472/uncaught-typeerror-data-some-is-not-a-function?rq=1